# How to copy text within quotes across multiple lines in vim like Sublime, and then paste it

Tags: vim, sublimetext2

I've been doing some digging, but can't seem to find a way to achieve a very similar functionality to that of Sublime's multi-line-select demonstrated by the giphy below:

1. copy all text within double quotes (so assuming something like
   `yi"`)
2. Do this across multiple lines
3. Paste all registers? or better yet all contents from a single register to a new buffer
4. add colons (turn into symbols) to each line of the pasted text
5. go to the end of each line and add a comma

I thought a visual selection and running `norm yi"` would do it, but it only captures the last line of the visual selection.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do these in Vim...

- yanking within quotes over multiple lines

  record a macro (`:let @a=''<cr>qq"Ayiw:let @A="\n"<cr>j"`)

  use the macro (`n@q`)
- pasting `a` into a new buffer (`:tabnew<cr>"ap`)
- add colons to the beginnings of multiple lines (`<c-v>njI:<esc>`)
- add commas to the ends of multiple lines (`<c-v>nj$A,<esc>`)

Maps and functions can also reduce the number of keystrokes for things.

e.g. `nnoremap <leader>b :tabnew<cr>p`

Comment: @daino3 The other way is a VimL (Python, Ruby, etc...) function, but at that point it might be worth checking out [plugins](https://github.com/terryma/vim-multiple-cursors) for multiple cursors.  Visual block select (`<c-v>`) is close, but it's not entirely the same and it has some limitations.